# Ruby - Modify Struct attribute immediately after it's being initialized

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :content)
book = Book.new('harry potter', 'a bunch of content here')
p book.title #=> harry potter
```

What I want the last line to produce is "Harry Potter". I know I can do something like:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :content) do
  def capitalized_title
    self.title.gsub(/\S+/, &:capitalize)
  end
end
```

and then call capitalized_title, but what I want is to not have to create a separate method, instead, have some way of when you assign "title" to a new Book object, the title is immediately capitalized. Some kind of hook method, I would guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Book < Struct.new(:title, :content)
  def title
    super.gsub(/\S+/, &:capitalize)
  end
end

book = Book.new('harry potter', 'a bunch of content here')
book.title # => "Harry Potter"
```

---

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :content) do
  alias orig_title title
  def title
    orig_title.gsub(/\S+/, &:capitalize)
  end
end
```

To prevent `title` is called every time, override `title=`:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :content) do
  alias orig_title= title=
  def initialize(*args)
    super
    self.title = title
  end
  def title= value
    self.orig_title = value.gsub(/\S+/, &:capitalize)
  end
end
```

Comment: Question in your first answer, is the `super.gsub` line invoked every time `book.title` is called?

Comment: @Anthony, You're right. I update the answer to include another code which does not call `gsub` every time.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `initialize` method for the class `Book` (borrowing @falsetru's nice way of capitalizing the the words in `title`).  First note that `Book` does not have its own `initialize` method;;

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :content)
  #=> Book
Book.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> []
```

Rather, it inherits from `Struct`:

```
Book.private_instance_methods.include?(:initialize)
  #=> true   
Book.instance_method(:initialize).owner
  #=> Struct
Struct.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:initialize, :initialize_copy]
```

We add an `initialize` method in the usual way:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :content) do
  def initialize(title,content)
    self.title = title.gsub(/\S+/, &:capitalize)
    self.content = content
  end
end
```

confirm:

```
Book.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:initialize]
```

and test:

```
book = Book.new('harry potter', 'a bunch of content here')
book.title
  #=> "Harry Potter"
book.content
  #=> "a bunch of content here"
```

If there were more than just two instance variables, we might do this:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :content) do
  def initialize(title,content)
    super
    self.title = title.gsub(/\S+/, &:capitalize)
  end
end
```